# How can I use the Facebook open graph to access the timeline cover photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How can I use the Facebook open graph to access the timeline cover photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no definitive way to read the user's current Cover photo but an acceptable workaround might be to access the user's photo albums and take the newest photo from the Cover Photos album

Comment: Hey lgy, Can you plz explain this a lil more..i didn't get it..Can't we change or upload the coverphoto progamtically? (using open graph APIs),i want to do this in an iPhone app.

Comment: You can't change the cover photo via the API, and when i posted that answer there also wasn't any explicit way to read the cover photo; you had to read the user's photo albums and find the 'Cover Photos' album and take the most recent entry. Now you can access the cover photo at `/USER_ID/?fields=cover`